# Old core wallet giving error at startup

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have a core wallet from 2011. a version 0.4.0 beta with almost 1 BTC.
When I start up bitcoin.exe I can see content and all my adresses, but it constantly pops up with an error saying:

EXCEPTION: 11DbException
Db::put: Not enough space

I still have 30 GB left on disk.

I would like to move the bitcoins to a newer wallet, but I'm afraid to lose them as the SW is very old.

What can you recommend I do?

As a sidenote: it is Bitcoin.exe I have started. bitcoin-qt.exe dies after trying to import blocks for a while. I'm not sure which one to use....

Thanks